# Sidekiq consuming more and more memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq

So I have a rails application and I'm using sidekiq 5.0.5 and sidekiq-cron 0.4.5. I have 3 scheduled cron jobs that run every 2,3, and 10 minutes, respectively. For whatever reason, after about 20-30 minutes, sidekiq gets killed for consuming too much memory.

If I open up `top` and watch the memory, I can constantly see it going up and up 2-3% every time the job executes.

Does anyone have any suggestions or maybe some alternatives to sidekiq? This is pretty annoying. I almost wonder if I just use the cron jobs in Linux to just simply run sidekiq to execute one background job, if it'd be cleaner and faster rather than having sidekiq constantly runinng and chewing up more memory.

I'm not sure if these will be necessary for troubleshooting purposes, but here's pretty much what I have configured in my application:

```
# config/sidekiq.yml
development:
  :concurrency: 50
production:
  :concurrency: 50
:queues:
  - default
```

.

```
# config/sidekiq_schedule.yml
job1:
  cron: "*/2 * * * *"
  class: "Refresh1"
  queue: default
  active_job: true

job2:
  cron: "*/2 * * * *"
  class: "Refresh2"
  queue: default
  active_job: true

job3:
  cron: "*/10 * * * *"
  class: "Refresh3"
  queue: default
  active_job: true
```

.

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
# if Rails.env.production?

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
        #config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: 2 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
        #config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: 52 }

    #Sidekiq scheduler.
    begin
        schedule_file = 'config/sidekiq_schedule.yml'

        if File.exists?(schedule_file) && Sidekiq.server?
                Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash! YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
        end
    rescue
        # Schedule file has commented schedules. Keep on moving.
    end

    Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
        Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server before disconnect is: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

        ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
                config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
            config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DATABASE_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
            # config['pool'] = ENV['WORKER_DB_POOL_SIZE'] || Sidekiq.options[:concurrency]
            config['pool'] = 16
            ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)

            Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server is now: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Your job runs for 30 minutes, eats all memory, gets killed and you blame sidekiq. Did I get this right?

Comment: Actually you didn't. From the sidekiq console, each job runs for approximately 24-40 seconds. For clarification, 25-30 minutes of this *repeated* task running means these tasks run for 24-40 seconds each, every 3 minutes, but after about 30 minutes, things start breaking.

Comment: i guess you need to reword your question around "after about 20-30 minutes of this repeated task running". It is, at best, ambiguous.

Comment: So these jobs, they don't run _once_ every 3 months? Is it months or minutes?

Comment: No. One runs every 2 minutes, the other every 3, and then the last runs every 10. My apologies, I've updated the original post.

Comment: Most likely culprit is your code, not sidekiq. If sidekiq was leaking memory, this would have been noticed and fixed very quickly.

Comment: Hmm. Think it's possible that even though the job is showing that it's done in the sidekiq console, that something is still going on?

Comment: Perhaps you save some data to global or class-level variables (or something like that)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll check into the code. I really appreciate the input. The jobs are scraping a website and saving updates to a model/database table. Lots of code in there so I'll skim through it. I assumed that by sidekiq saying the job was done that everything executed and terminated. Thanks again man!